# Intermittent problem publishing InfoPath 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, windows-7

I'm having intermittent problems publishing from InfoPath Designer 2013 to SharePoint Online.

I created a new Form library, went to Library Settings/Advanced/Edit Template to open the Template in InfoPath Designer.

I saved the Template and tried to Publish the Form.

- When I tried to Quick Publish, I got a message that the library did not exist.
- When I tried Publishing, InfoPath could not (would not) find the new Form library.
- When I tried Publishing to a new SP Library, I got a message that I couldn't Publish because SP is not in my Trusted Locations (although it is in my Trusted Sites).

But these problems don't happen all the time.  I was able to Publish a Form last week.  Any idea what's happening here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there must have been something wrong with the library.  I deleted it and used InfoPath to create a new form library with the same form and it worked.